# OpenCV multithreading with Mats

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv

Hey! So I am working on an assignment about multi-threading with OpenCV. My question is as follows. How can I get all my threads to work on the same image (stored in a Mat)? I know making copies would make it slow and thus multi-threading would have no sense. Also, I would like to control the number of threads I use, and even tho I have seen the lambda c++ 11 introduced I do not know how to make it so that I control the number of threads.

I currently have a function that calculates every pixel to be put in the image, so my code running on serial looks something like this:

```
for(int i=0;r<MyMat.cols;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<MyMat.rows;j++){
        uchar value = (uchar) MyFunction(i,j);
        MyMat.ptr<uchar>(i)[j] = value;
    }
}
```

English is not my mother tongue, if I did not explain myself properly please ask for clarifications. Any help is good help!

Comment: If you modify `Mat`, then you may need hard copy of the original `Mat`. For threads that do not modify `Mat`, you can just use global variable to assign `Mat`.

Comment: there's not so much special about opencv Mat. One nice feature could be that you can add a padding at the end of each row which might or might not help you getting some nice memory access behaviour. If you have to "modify" the image you might instead want to save the result in another Mat instead of real modification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you split the image into horizontal bands, each thread can work on its own band independently. If each thread does not change any image data beyond its band, it should work.

In fact, OpenCV supports this already. 
Take a look at [`parallel_for_`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/dff/tutorial_how_to_use_OpenCV_parallel_for_.html) and how it is used.

Comment: Thanks! I have seen parallel_for, the thing is I want to controll the number of threads I create, and so far I do not know how to do it with parallel_for. Actually read the Mandelbrot example in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you! I will look it up

Comment: @RodrigoAlvarado: If this helped, mark the answer as answered :-)